I am extracting images from a PDF file. Then I am applying deskewing on it to correct the orientation. However it is failing in certain cases
Fixture details
In this Fixture 5 is getting rotated properly, whereas Fixture 6 is not getting rotated properly and is in a downright position. Please help
def deskew2(image):
    coords = np.column_stack(np.where(image > 0))
    print(coords[:,(1,0)])
    angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords[:,(1,0)])[-1]
    if angle < -45:
        angle = -(90 + angle)
    else:
        angle = -angle
    print(angle)
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)  # Adjust the center to the middle of the image
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)

    # Calculate the new bounding dimensions of the image
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])
    new_w = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    new_h = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (new_w / 2) - center[0]
    M[1, 2] += (new_h / 2) - center[1]

    rotated = cv2.=arpAffine(image, M, (new_w, new_h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, 
    borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    return rotated

